# ffmpeg video output is desaturated

Tags: c++, opengl, ffmpeg

I'm trying to get my view from my application (using OpenGL) to be written to a file.
This is how I get the OpenGL frame:

```
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, renderTexture->getTextureData()->glId);    
glGetTexImage(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixels);
```

This works fine and has the right colors. (I checked this by rendering the pixels to a single image file).

Now, since I want this in a video I'm using ffmpeg for the encoding. This is my command:

```
ffmpeg -r 24 -pix_fmt rgba -s 1280x720  -f rawvideo -y -i - -vf vflip -vcodec mpeg1video -q:v 4 -bufsize 500KB -maxrate 5000KB
```

This also "works" but my video is very desaturated compared with the actual input it gets from OpenGL. How can I solve this? (if possible, can I do this by only changing things in the command?)

Comment: You should use glReadPixels instead of going through glGetTexImage. Two reasons: glGetTexImage is not supported by OpenGL-ES and glReadPixels even works without having to go through a FBO if you want to get the contents of your main window.

Comment: @datenwolf thanks for the information. I'll try that but I don't suspect this will change the output from ffmpeg

Comment: Indeed it doesn't address your problem, hence this being a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the way ffmpeg reads the pixels doesn't match the layout you get out of OpenGL. Use glPixelStorei with the GL_PACK_… parameters to pin down the layout OpenGL emits.

Another problem may be color spaces. You've to make sure that ffmpeg operates in the very same color space as your OpenGL context. If not you've to determine the color spaces and add a conversion filter into ffmpeg's processing chain.

Comment: I added `glPixelStorei(GL_PACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);` before the `glBindTexture` and `glGetTexImage` call but it doesn't seem to change anything. Any idea how I would set conversion filter? (I've tried with `-pix_fmt` but I can't find one that fixes it. I guess it should be converted from the original RGBA to yuv420p)

Comment: @Dries: `ffmpeg -pix_fmts` (note the `s` at the end) lists you all the pixel formats ffmpeg understands. However some formats like RGB are not well defined. For example there are different ways to apply gamma curves, set the primary points and so on. If you really want to be on the safe side you should first convert (using OpenGL with a shader) to a contact color space (like Lab or XYZ) and pass that to ffmpeg. Or do the conversion to YUV444 (which is also well defined) and pass that to ffmpeg. ffmpeg can do the chroma subsampling to YUV422 for you.

Comment: Isn't it kind of stupid that I have to do this myself (if this is indeed the only option). I would've guessed ffmpeg is equipped to deal with this

Comment: @Dries: Well, color spaces are a tricky subject. To be honest, when dealing with OpenGL renderings there are, in most cases  actually only 3 color spaces to consider: *linear RGB(A)*, *sRGB(A) with linear alpha* and *sRGB(A) with nonlinear alpha*. These are also among the color spaces ffmpeg natively supports.